# Blocking dict in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, dictionary

Is there a data structure in Python that resembles a blocking dictionary? This data structure must fulfill these requirements:

- it must be randomly accessible and allow any element to be modified/deleted (not just the first or last)
- it must have a blocking get() and put()
- it must be thread-safe

I would have used a queue but, although blocking and thread-safe, it's not randomly accessible. A dict is not blocking either (as far as my Python knowledge goes).
As an example, think of one producer thread adding key-value pairs to such a data-structure (updating values for existing keys if already present - this is where a queue won't cut it), and a worker blocking on get() and consuming these key-value pairs as they become available.
Many many thanks!

edit:
Let's assume the producer polls a CI server and gets project-status pairs. It generates the differences in project statuses and puts them in the aforementioned data structure. The worker picks up these project-status updates and displays them one by one as an animation on the screen.

```
class Producer:
  def generateProjectStatusChanges():
    ...
  def updateSuperAwesomeDataStructure(changes):
    for (proj, stat) in changes:
      #queue won't do cause the update could take place in the middle of the queue
      #hence the dict behavior
      superAwesomeDS.putOrUpdate(proj, stat) 
  def watchForUpdates():
     changes = generateProjectStatusChanges()
     updateSuperAwesomeDataStructure(changes)
     time.sleep(self.interval)

class Worker:
  def blockingNotifyAnimation():
    ...
  def watchForUpdates():
    while true:
      proj, stat = superAwesomeDS.getFirstPair() #or any pair really
      blockingNotifyAnimation(proj, stat)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along the following lines should do the trick (untested):

```
class UpdatableBlockingQueue(object):

  def __init__(self):
    self.queue = {}
    self.cv = threading.Condition()

  def put(self, key, value):
    with self.cv:
      self.queue[key] = value
      self.cv.notify()

  def pop(self):
    with self.cv:
      while not self.queue:
        self.cv.wait()
      return self.queue.popitem()
```

It uses a dictionary for the queue and a condition variable for serialising access and signalling between threads.

Comment: Might as well use `with self.cv` here instead of `acquire`/`release`. Your code is dangerous when an unhashable item is `put` into the dict; using `with` makes it safe. On Python 3.2+ you also have `wait_for` which is a bit of syntax sugar. And finally, note that `notify` might need to become `notify_all` if you use this to wait on a particular key becoming available without making several condition variables.